# Java DB and jasper report nested select

Tags: java, select, nested, jasper-reports, javadb

I'm creating nested select view to be run in Jasper Netbeans report from JAVA DB , and need to distinct the grouped based on same below statement either by `CASE` injected inside the select or using `if` is workable inside JAVA DB or any other way, last I want to use record set as source query  to run jasper report  my code as follows

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 try {
   String host1= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//home/mohamed/java- 
   progs/SPaccounting/accountsdb/accountsdb;create=true";
   String uName1="rootuser";
   String uPass1="1234a1234b";
   con1=DriverManager.getConnection(host1,uName1 ,uPass1);
   String sql1="select sum(journal_amount) AS DR ,0 as CR, journal_crname  AS 
   ACCNAME FROM JOURNAL
   GROUP BY journal_CRNAME UNION select 0 AS DR,sum(journal_amount) AS   CR,  
   journal_dbname AS ACCNAME FROM JOURNAL
   GROUP BY journal_DRNAME order by ACCNAME
   ";
   JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,param1,connect); //add param    
   if   required    
   String jrxmlFileName = "/home/mohamed/java-progs/accounting syst em/     
   JavaAaccountingsys/src/report1.jrxml";
   JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jrxmlFileName);


   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null,    con1);
   JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint); 
   } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

The output is:

```
ACCNAME     DR       CR
--------    ----    -----
CASH         1,200   0
AMRO BANK    0       500
CASH         0       600
AMRO BANK    700     0
```

I want to distinct and  sum above and cut debt `DR` from  credit `CR` and get result as following report :

```
ACCNAME     DR       CR
--------    ----    -----
CASH         600     0
AMRO BANK    200     0
```

Please assist in correcting select statement

Comment: Can't understand how CASH 1200-600 = 100?

Comment: you are right thank you sir i will revise Cash should be 600

Comment: @Petter  Yes this solved since 12 Jan. now apart of my history skills thxs for the efforts

Comment: Great thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes I have got the correct select statement in SO, grouping the output in one nested package adding below select statement the reports working fine 
then just create a subquery to get the final step

```
SELECT ACCNAME,
CASE WHEN SUM(CREDIT - DEBT) < 0 THEN - SUM(CREDIT - DEBT)
ELSE 0
 END DEBT,
   CASE WHEN SUM(CREDIT - DEBT) > 0 THEN   SUM(CREDIT - DEBT)
        ELSE 0
   END CREDIT
FROM ( ...... ) myTable
GROUP BY ACCNAME ;
```

Thus i was got the right path .